# Pyspark.sql : how to remove the empty space and retain only specific part of data using python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my table: Lat_Long

[image]

I want to retain only the information which is marked.

[image]

So the table should appear like this

[image]

How to achieve this using pyspark sql using python and the column data type is in string format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `regexp_extract` and the regular expression `(\S+)$` to get the last number. For example:

```
+---------+---------+
|     col1|     col2|
+---------+---------+
|100 -20.0|300 -40.0|
|100 -20.0|300 -40.0|
+---------+---------+

df.select(*[F.regexp_extract(col, r'(\S+)$', 1).alias(col) for col in df.columns]).show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+
| col1| col2|
+-----+-----+
|-20.0|-40.0|
|-20.0|-40.0|
+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` to split on spaces. Use a regex `\s+` to split on any number of spaces.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.select(*[F.split(i, r'\s+')[1].alias(i) for i in df.columns])
```